# Post to Facebook page with IFTTT as post not as album

Tags: facebook-pages, if-this-then-that

I want to post an image with text as a Facebook page post.

There are three options on IFTTT:

1. Text post (where it doesn't let me post images)
2. Website (not what I'm looking for)
3. Album post (posts as an album, not as a post)

Is it possible?

Comment: What are you doing to the initiating from? Email? Some other service?

Answer (score 2):

You want to choose #3 - `Album post` aka [upload a photo from url](https://ifttt.com/channels/facebook_pages/actions/30-upload-a-photo-from-url).

This will still *"post"* the photo to facebook but also add it to the album you choose.

---

Unfortunately, on Facebook all photos are actually part of an album. By default photo posts created on Facebook are part of the `Timeline Photos` album. [Source](https://www.facebook.com/help/174641285926169).

On IFTTT if you leave the `Album` field blank it will be added to the `IFTTT Photos` Album.

Answer (score -1):

I found that if you name the album (in your IFTTT settings) "Timeline Photos" then the image and post comes in as a post with a full image; and without Facebook describing that you added a photo to an album.